# What to do with now irrelevant answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, etiquette

I [asked a question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/did-moshe-keep-mitzvos-on-mount-sinai) and wasn't sufficiently clear as to what kind of answers I was looking for. This resulted in several answers that didn't really address what I wanted at all. I edited my question to clarify what I wanted, but now there are still those answers, which now obviously don't fit the question.

What should I do?

- Leave them?
- Edit a disclaimer into the answers to say they were on a previous version of the question?
- Comment on the answers, notifying the authors of the change.

  - If there's no response, flag for moderator?

**While I'm also interested in this specific case, primarily, I'm interested in the general case.** The ideal answer would address both.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/

Answer (score 3):

I would edit a short note into the answers (something like "this answer addressed a previous version of the question") and post a comment on each to alert the authors.  That way they can come back and rework if they want to, but in the meantime it's clear to the reader who comes across the page what is going on.

Comment: here's what I added to all the answers when I clarified my question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9903/why-does-there-seem-to-be-different-standards-for-future-sinners  -- "I've restructured my question to emphasize what I'm looking for, but this may invalidate most of the answers already given. Not sure if this is an issue, discuss on chat."